# I need some help getting rid of a body

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I've just lifted the siege of Battlehorn Castle and there are bodies everywhere. I'd really like to make my new home presentable. I am, after all, a lord now.

I'm trying to lift the hands and feet and head because they seem the easiest, but I'm really not making very much progress. It's been 10 minutes and Lord Kelvyn is barely out of the portcullis.

Is there a trick to moving bodies I'm just not seeing?

If it matters, I'm a level 1 Wood Elf, sign of the Thief, with a custom class specializing in Block, Hand to Hand, Alchemy, Alteration, Acrobatics, Marksman and Speechcraft. My luck is severely reduced (it's down from 65 to 15 after doing a quest... I have to heal that some time...)

Comment: I forgot this used to be a problem. Skyrim and Fus Ro Dah really spoiled us.

Answer (score 31):

Grabbing and dragging them works, but as you've noticed, it's kind of slow.  I find generally pulling works a bit better than pushing, so you might try grabbing and *slowly* dragging so as not to lose your grip.

It sounds like you've got a lot of cleanup on the horizon, though, so perhaps more drastic measures are in order.

You could [Reanimate](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Reanimate), but the easiest method of doing that is probably the [Staff of Worms](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Staff_of_Worms) which is going to be hard for a level 1 Thief to get.  If you had it, you could just cast it and have the not-quite-dead NPCs follow you somewhere else before the expire yet again.

You could also try some sort of magic, perhaps a [fire-type spell](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Fire_Damage) that has a nice explosion effect.  You can't really "aim" it as well, but hey, it's faster corpse movement, so there's that.

Alternatively, you could try traveling somewhere else, preferably a distant indoors environment, and waiting for a few consecutive days before returning.  The location will tend to reset, giving you that "new home" feel and purging the corpse stink almost like magic.  For best results, wait at *least* [3 days](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Respawning) before returning.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand if dead bodies in Battlehorn Castle stay even after the respawn timeout.  Since Battlehorn Castle is an owned location, I think things inside it are considered "safe."

Comment: I was away for some time, including a level-up sleep (can you say... level 2 Thief? mmmhmm) but they weren't gone away. I didn't track exactly how long. I think I'm going to try to keep them around if the game lets me, but I want to display them in a better way. I'd also like to take them to the top of the wall and throw them over the edge. I had fun doing that to one of the guards who perished up there and... and I'm officially on the NSA's watch list now... I'll let you know how the fire spells work.

Answer (score 19):

If you're playing on PC and don't mind using [console commands](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console), this should be relatively easy. Open the console (<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>§</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> key depending on your keyboard - the one below Esc), click on the body, type in "disable" and hit enter. Rinse and repeat as necessary.